# Keep specification format of `pyproject.toml` unchanged in automated dependabot pull requests

Tags: python, pyproject.toml, dependabot, github-dependabot

Consider a python package with package specifications in `pyproject.toml`. All the required and optional dependencies are specified in the format:

```ini
...
    "package_name<upper_bound,>=lower_bound",
...
```

This is according to [`pyproject-fmt`](https://github.com/tox-dev/pyproject-fmt), which is also part of the configured `pre-commit` hooks.

The Github repository is configured with Dependabot, and while it detects a new release of `package_name`, it is trying to make the above line change to the following:

```ini
...
    "package_name>=lower_bound,<new_upper_bound",
...
```

This is causing CI failure which is running `pre-commit` and the formatter tool tries to change it back in the consistent format it is using.

My question is whether there is a way to configure Dependabot such that it modifies the upper bound in place without rewriting the line, something like this:

```ini
...
    "package_name<new_upper_bound,>=lower_bound",
...
```

Comment: This question is based on the observations in https://github.com/sktime/sktime/pull/5443. The workaround I can think of this modify the CI with an auto-commit step to apply the suggested changes and re-trigger on that commit.